# Python "While" Loops and Breaking Them

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

If I have two `while:` loops, one inside of the other, like such:

```
while #test :
    while #test :
        #other code
        if #test :
           break
    #other code
```

Will the `break` stop both `while:` loops or only the one where the `if #test :` is in?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it is only 4 lines of code. Why dont you try it on the terminal ?

Comment: Hint for future questions about keywords: you could have typed `help("break")` at the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would only stop the inner loop.  If you wanted to break both loops, you'd have to provide another condition to break in the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

A `break` always breaks only the loop enclosing it, so the last line of the code will be executed under the outer loop.

[Learn](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) [more](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement)

Answer (score 1):

[From python documentation:](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement)

> break may only occur syntactically nested in a for or while loop, but
>   not nested in a function or class definition within that loop.
>
> It terminates the nearest enclosing loop, skipping the optional else
>   clause if the loop has one.

"break terminates the nearest eclosing loop" - e.g. only inner while

Answer (score 0):

break only stop the one where the if #test,so the other code will be exec.